# How to perform internal login in feathresjs?

Tags: node.js, express, feathersjs

**Steps to reproduce:**

- Create a generic service.
- before hook in the create method. It should check the payload and retrieve the email from the payload.
- By using that payload, Get the user record from users table, and request auth service with email and password

**Expected behavior:**

In the response of this api, user should recieve the authToken after successful login.

**Actual behavior:**

User gets Invalid login error because the password in db is hashed. and the authenticate() compares the password after hashing the password payload.

I've created a git issue as well, you can check the same [here](https://github.com/feathersjs/feathers/issues/1764).

Comment: Why would you need to authenticate the user in this case? What do you actually need to do?

Comment: Is your service authenticating the user some other way? There are ways of using authentication strategies to do that.